# ARM templates how to add public IP to dns zone

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I'm using arm templates for deployments (preferable bicep). Is there a simple way to add my public ip resource to preexisting DNS zone? Public IP has property named dnsSettings, but it seems that it only can set DNS pointing to azure default domain publicipname.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com, instead of publicipname.customdomain.com.

```
resource publicIp 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses@2020-11-01' = {
  location: rg_location
  name: 'pip-example'
  tags: tags_list
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard'
    tier: 'Regional'
  }
  properties:{
    dnsSettings:{
      domainNameLabel: 'publicipname'
      fqdn: 'publicipname.customdomain.com'
    }
    publicIPAllocationMethod: 'Static'
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you have that DNS zone? In your Azure or in external DNS provider?

Comment: And please add the term "Bicep" to your question. Otherwise it is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You could register the `PublicIP` resource directly in DNS like:

```
...
resource dns 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones@2018-05-01' = {
  name: 'customdomain.com'
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    zoneType: 'Public'
  }
}

resource dnsEntry 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/A@2018-05-01' = {
  name: 'publicipname'
  parent: dns
  properties: {
    TTL: 3600
    targetResource: {
      id: publicIp.id
    }
  }
}
```

or with the IP address

```
resource dns 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones@2018-05-01' = {
  name: 'customdomain.com'
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    zoneType: 'Public'
  }
}

resource dnsEntry 'Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/A@2018-05-01' = {
  name: 'publicipname'
  parent: dns
  properties: {
    TTL: 3600
    ARecords: [
      {
        ipv4Address: publicIp.properties.ipAddress
      }
    ]
  }
}
```